# Freeze Columns from right to left

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, freeze

I have a data grid in which I need to freeze the rightmost column.
It is no problem to freeze the columns from left to right with the [FrozenColumnCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount.aspx) property.

Does anyone of you know how to do this?

Thx in advance,

TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to Freeze a column to the right if you want the others to scroll.  If this functionality is critical to your app I would suggest investigating the third party Silverlight grid controls on the market e.g. Telerik, Infragistics etc