# Freezing Column in datagrid of Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a data grid in which I need to freeze the rightmost column. It is no problem to freeze the columns from left to right with the FrozenColumnCount property.

Does anyone of you know how to do this??

i m in trouble some one please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Columns of starting.
It can not be done for last columns.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterAllignmentCell}">
                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate >
                                            <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Width="16" Height="16" Cursor="Hand" Content="Delete" Margin="0,0,0,0" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand,Source={StaticResource AlertListViewModel}}" 
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding AlertId}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding IsDeleteRight,Source={StaticResource AlertListViewModel}}">
                                                <Button.Template>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/TFM;component/Images/ic-delete.png" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Delete"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Button.Template>
                                            </Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the standard DataGrid the answer is no.  See my previous response to the same question:

[Freeze Columns from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969429/freeze-columns-from-right-to-left/7145903#7145903)